# How to test nested firestore batch functions in redux saga using jest?

Tags: firebase, testing, google-cloud-firestore, jestjs, redux-saga

In a react project I have a redux-saga file which I create and save new items on firebase backend(firestore).

In that saga function, I am getting a new write batch object first, then I update the firestore document, and finally I commit the batch.

**Saga Worker**

```js
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import { db } from './firebase' // db: firebase.firestore()

export function* mySaga(item) {
    try {
        // init firestore batch.
        const batch = yield call(db, db.batch)

        // Set firestore document and save new item.
        const itemRef = yield call ([db, db.doc], `/items/${item.id}`)
        yield call([batch, batch.set], itemRef , item)

        // Commit the batch.
        yield call([batch, batch.commit])


        yield put({type: 'success'})
    } catch (err) {
        yield put({type: 'error', payload: err})
    }
}
```

**Saga Worker's Test**

```js
import * as sagas from './mySaga'

describe('mySaga', () => {
    const spyOnDoc = jest.spyOn(db, 'doc')

    it('handles item creation', async () => {

        const dispatched = []
        await runSaga(
            { dispatch: action => dispatched.push(action) },
            sagas.mySaga,
        ).toPromise()

        expect(spyOnDoc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

        // !!! Here I need to check for nested set and commit functions of the batch object created in saga.

    })
})
```

How can I test the batch function's nested "set" and "commit" functions to check if they are called x times and called with proper inputs?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After several attemps I figured out a way to accomplishing this kind of tests. In case if someone needs this solution, here it is.

`db.batch()` method creates a `firebase.firestore.WriteBatch` object. And this object has `commit`, `set`, `update` and `delete` methods. More details can be found [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.WriteBatch).

**Final Saga Worker's Test**

```js
import * as sagas from './mySaga'
import { db } from './firebase' // db: firebase.firestore()

describe('mySaga', () => {
    const spyOnDoc = jest.spyOn(db, 'doc')

    // We are mocking the methods of this predefined object.
    firestore.WriteBatch.set = jest.fn()
    firestore.WriteBatch.commit = jest.fn()

    // Then we implement those created mocks into the batch's mock implementation.
    const spyOnBatch = jest.spyOn(db, 'batch').mockImplementation(() => ({
        set: firestore.WriteBatch.set,
        commit: firestore.WriteBatch.commit,
    }))

    it('handles item creation', async () => {

        const dispatched = []
        await runSaga(
            { dispatch: action => dispatched.push(action) },
            sagas.mySaga,
            {id: 123} // Item
        ).toPromise()

        expect(spyOnDoc).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)

        // Finally, we can test those nested object functions as below.
        expect(firestore.WriteBatch.commit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(firestore.WriteBatch.set).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        expect(firestore.WriteBatch.set).toHaveBeenCalledWith(db.doc('/items/123'), {id: 123})

    })
})
```